# Is there any way to send the uploaded data (e.g. image file) on slack to on-premise server?

Tags: server, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I am currently looking for a way to upload data (ex. image file) on slack and immediately send it to a on-premise server from slack. Does anyone know if this is possible or if so how to do it?